# automatically disconnnect network drives in xp

Tags: windows

how to automatically disconnnect  network drives in xp  which are connected during system startup ?

Answer (score 3):

```
net use X: \\foo /delete
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all drives...

Net Use /delete /y *

Comment: like this one if you are in an environment where no one has custom mapped drives, as in drives other then those mapped by the login script. 

If users do have custom mapped drives they usually get pretty angry when to add this to the logon script and delete them. :S

Comment: Very true... I try to keep a tight leash on the network drives in my environment, so it works very well here...!